# Passing a default value to a Ruby method, one level deep

Tags: ruby, methods, default

If I have the following Ruby code:

```
def result(b=25)
  puts b
end
```

then I can simply call `result`, and 25 will be output. So far, no problem.

But I'd like to call it from another method, like this:

```
def outer(a,b)
  #...do some stuff with a...
  result(b)
end
```

and I'd like `outer(1,5)` to output 5, but `outer(1)` to simply output 25. In effect, I want to pass "undefined" through to the `result` method.

Is there any way I can do this? (I can't simply use `def outer(a,b=25)`, sadly, because the default value for `b` is actually an instance variable of the class in which `result` is a method.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about this:

```
def outer(a,b = nil)
  ...do some stuff with a...
  result(*[b].compact)
end
```

That will call result(b) if b is not nil and result() if b is nil

Comment: I don't think this works. Doesn't the OP just want to call result(b) if b is nil?

Answer (score 0):

An option to solve this would be to put b behind a getter method:

```
def get_b
  @b
end

def outer(a, b = get_b)
  #...do some stuff with a...
  result(b)
end
```

Comment: This would only be guaranteed to work if the setter method was guaranteed to be called before 'outer' gets called, right? If the setter isn't called, the @b won't be set to anything yet. The OP wanted the value to default in that case. I guess the getter could be conditional and return the default if @b isn't set yet.

Answer (score 0):

My proposed solution changes your initial problem just a tiny bit, but it's close.
You can default the second value of outer with the inner method, and then call the inner method again. It works a bit strangely if you are actually outputting something, but if you don't call puts, it works pretty well.

```
def result(b=25)
  b
end

def outer(a, b = result)
  #...do stuff with a...
  puts result(b)
end
```

This will assign the default to b only if you don't provide it. If you do provide it, it will then use that b in result. Functionally it seems to work the way you want it, the only caveat is that if your inner method were doing something non-trivial, you would be duplicating the work in the default case.